# Capturar pressionamento de uma tecla em segundo plano

Tags: vb.net

Olá, gostaria de fazer com que minha aplicação detectasse quando uma determinada tecla é pressionada, porém em segundo plano, ou seja, não haverá nenhum formulário em exibição.
Consigo fazer a detecção das teclas no formulário com o código (Ctrl+L):

```
   If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.L Then
       MessageBox.Show("Teste")
   End If
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Em c++ tem uma função chamada GetAsyncKeyState que serve para detectar se um determinada tecla está sendo pressionada naquele momento de modo assíncrono. Para usar essa função vc teria que importar uma biblioteca que a implementasse e ver se ela funcionária em uma linguagem de alto nível como vb.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos usar a função `GetAsyncKeyState()` do C++ como o @viniciusafx mencionou no comentário da sua pergunta, para isso, vamos criar uma referência para ela.

```
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vkey As Long) As Integer
```

Agora vamos criar o verificador para quando essa tecla está pressionada ou não, para isso vamos criar um `Timer` com intervalo para `25ms` (quanto menor o intervalo, melhor, porém poderá consumir mais processador na execução. Quanto maior o intervalo, por mais tempo o usuário deverá pressionar a tecla para chamar a ação).

```
Private WithEvents Timer1 As New Timer With {
     .Interval = 25,  ' 25 ms
     .Enabled  = True ' ativa o timer
}
```

Agora vamos criar o código para o evento `Tick`:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Click() Handles Timer1.Tick
    ...
End Sub
```

Agora, dentro do método acima, vamos declarar três booleanas, uma para distinguir se a tecla *Ctrl* está sendo pressionada, outra para ver se a tecla *Shift* é pressionada, e então, outra para saber se a tecla que quer que seja pressionada esteja sendo pressionada:

```
Private ctrlKey As Boolean  = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.ControlKey)
Private shiftKey As Boolean = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Shiftkey)
Private theKey As Boolean   = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.K)
```

No código abaixo, irá detectar a combinação *Ctrl + Shift + K*:

```
If ctrlKey = True And shiftKey = True And theKey = True Then
     ' código aqui...
End If
```

Se quiser numa opção mais rápida, para a combinação *Ctrl + X*:

```
If ctrlKey = True And (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.X) = True) Then
     ' pressionou Ctrl + X
End If
```

Fonte do código: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/94406-global-hotkey/